# C++ / Boost:: Propery_Tree - Is it possible to take ini config value with dot in name

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Here is my code:

My `Config.h`:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

class Config {
public:
    Config(std::string conf);

    template<typename T>
    T GetConfigValue(std::string configKey, T value = 0){
        pt::ptree tree;
        pt::read_ini(_configFile, tree);
        return tree.get<T>(configKey, value);
    }

private:
    std::string _configFile;
};
```

Here is how I call it:

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Config.h"
int main() {
    Config * config = new Config("/WorldServer.conf.dist");
    std::string def = "Nothing there.";
    Logger::Log(config->GetConfigValue("WorldServer.MaxPingTime", def));
}
```

Here is the content of `WorldServer.conf.dist`:

```
[WorldServer]
MaxPingTime = 30
MySQL.User = "root"
```

When I execute

`Logger::Log(config->GetConfigValue("WorldServer.MaxPingTime", def));`

I see `30` as result which is correct, however when I execute:

`Logger::Log(config->GetConfigValue("WorldServer.MySQL.User", def));`

i see as result `Nothing there.`

As far as I understand the `.` in the `MySQL.User` is causing the issue.

My question is can I somehow make it work with dot using boost property tree to parse the ini config?

Comment: You can use a `boost::property_tree::ptree::path_type` with alternate separators, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50288836).

Comment: Thanks that solved the question.

Comment: Please remember to upvote so others will be able to find this more easily.